# Dialogflow V2 Webhook with PHP on EC2

Tags: php, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I have found the Dialogflow V2 API to be very confusing.  I have a restful api that is built with PHP on EC2 and RDS/MYSQL.   I am using it for my Dialogflow V1 API bot to provide the webhook.  However, it seems like to use it for the V2 I need to have it on Google Cloud PHP?   Is it a correct statement?   I been struggling with it for almost 2 weeks and not having any success.

Note:  I am not using the enterprise version for dialogflow as I am building a demo for a co-worker.

Comment: no, you can have the webhook anywhere, even on your local system.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not correct. You can run your webhook or use the API anywhere.

If you're just using it for webhook fulfillment, then there are very few differences between the V1 and V2 protocol. Primarily, some field names were changed and some of the values you need to use are full ID paths rather than a short form of the ID.

If you are using the API to dynamically change the Intents or to make User Entities, there *have* been a number of differences, but most of them map fairly cleanly to new concepts. The biggest change is how you authenticate those API calls.